Regex to match a whole number not ending in some digits
I've not been able to construct a pattern which can return an whole numbers that don't end in a sequence of digits. The numbers could be of any length, even single digits, but they will always be whole. Additionally, multiple numbers could be on the same line of text and I want to match them all. The numbers are always followed by either a  single space or the end of the line or the end of the text. I'm matching in python 3.12
For example, over the text '12345 67890 123175 9876', let's say I want to get all numbers not ending in 175.
I would want the following matches:
12345
67890
9876

I've tried using the following:

\d+(?<!175)(\b|$), which matched 3 empty strings,

text = "12345 67890 123175 9876"
matches = findall(r"\d+(?<!175)(\b|$)", text)
print(matches)
> ['', '', '']


\d+(?!175)(\b|$), which matched 4 empty strings,

text = "12345 67890 123175 9876"
matches = findall(r"\d+(?!175)(\b|$)", text)
print(matches)
> ['', '', '', '']


\d+(?<!175), which matched all 4 numbers

matches = findall(r"\d+(?<!175)", text)
> ['12345', '67890', '12317', '9876']


\d+(?:175), which matched only the number ending in 175

matches = findall(r"\d+(?:175)", text)
> ['123175']


If your string is comprised solely of whitespace delimited numbers it's going to be faster to simply split and compare - i.e., no need for re

@SIGHUP Can you show some data backing your assertion? The speed of a regex match depends a lot on the pattern, whether it backtracks and not, and somewhat on the regex engine. A split-and-filter approach would require making at least two passes, so, theoretically, it can't be faster than a regex parser that is consuming tokens as it goes.

This isn't a matter of performance, I want to know how to do it in regex and everyone who searches this and sees the title of it will too.

@adi That's why it was a comment rather than an answer. I only provided a demonstration because I was asked to prove my assertion. Take it or leave it

And all you needed was \b instead of (\b|$).

@WiktorStribiżew I assume you’re referring to the pattern\d+(?<!175)\b. While it works, it takes more steps than the possessive version, presumably due to backtracking.

Because of placements. \b\d+\b(?<!175) will be more efficient, but the question is not about efficiency.

I appreciate that the question is about regular expressions and not alternative techniques for achieving the same objectives. I have however edited my demo to incorporate the various suggestions in real answers for comparison purposes

You get empty strings as re.findall() returns the value of the capture group, which you are having using (\b|$) so just \b will work. See re.findall behaves weird

You can use is a negative lookbehind .*(?<!a) that ensures the string does not end with a.
\d++(?<!175)

Test here.
Note that Possessive Quantifier (++) has been introduced in Python 3.11. Your 2nd approach from revision 1 was close, but not correct since the Greedy quantifier (+) would eat up all the digits, and then try to backtrack.

Demonstration of how a simple split and compare can be faster than using regular expressions:
import re
from timeit import timeit
import sys
import random

s = " ".join([str(random.randint(10_000, 1_000_000)) for _ in range(10_000)])

P1 = re.compile(r"\d+")

def func2():
    return [v for v in P1.findall(s) if not v.endswith("175")]

func2.__doc__ = f"re {P1.pattern} with string comparison"

P3 = re.compile(r"\b\d+\b(?<!175)") # Wiktor Stribiżew

def func2a():
    return P3.findall(s)

func2a.__doc__ = f"re {P3.pattern}"

def func3():
    """Split/compare (no re)"""
    return [v for v in s.split() if not v.endswith("175")]

def func4():
    """Split/compare (no re) with integer check"""
    return [v for v in s.split() if not v.endswith("175") and v.isdecimal()]

funclist = [func2, func2a, func3, func4]

if sys.version_info.major >= 3 and sys.version_info.minor >= 11:
    P2 = re.compile(r"\d++(?<!175)")

    def func1():
        return P2.findall(s)

    func1.__doc__ = f"re {P2.pattern}"
    funclist.append(func1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for func in funclist:
        duration = timeit(func, number=5_000)
        print(func.__doc__, f"{duration:.4f}s")

    if __debug__:
        # assert that all functions return the same results
        for f1, f2 in zip(funclist, funclist[1:]):
            try:
                assert f1() == f2()
            except AssertionError:
                print("Assertion failed", f1.__name__, f2.__name__)
    else:
        print("Not in debug mode. Assertions not tested")

Output:
re \d+ with string comparison 4.9359s
re \b\d+\b(?<!175) 4.7224s
Split/compare (no re) 1.9434s
Split/compare (no re) with integer check 2.7146s
re \d++(?<!175) 3.9377s

Platform:
Python 3.13.1
MacOS 15.2
Apple M2


Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I’ve upvoted you. I’m still curious why this is showing what it’s showing, so, I may use your code to dig deeper.

@AbhijitSarkar Maybe the re engine isn't as efficient as one might hope in 3.13.0. Also, just for fun, I've edited the demo' to show how one could isolate whole numbers without re and show revised results

Could be. FWIW, starting the pattern with \b drastically improves the timing in regex101, but performs worse in your code.  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Your first attempt \d+(?<!175)(\b|$) was almost right, just made the mistake of capturing the \b|$ so findall returned that instead of the matched number. You can fix it by not capturing there with \d+(?<!175)(?:\b|$), or simply with \d+(?<!175)\b (since the $ is pointless there). Or the perhaps clearer \d+\b(?<!175).

All of these take more steps than the possessive version, presumably due to backtracking.

@AbhijitSarkar And that makes this answer "not useful"? They didn't ask for something optimal, and as you know, the possessive version doesn't exist in all alive Python versions. So I'd say it's a least useful for the older versions. And I'd say the explanation of their mistake is useful, too.

And that makes this answer "not useful" - I didn't say that, so, not sure why you think so. I merely stated a fact, so that the OP or anyone else can choose wisely. If they aren't running Py 3.11+, they can use the greedy version. Otherwise, they can use whichever is more performant, even one of the non-regex answers.

Ah, gotcha, so iiuc, the final pattern will match numbers that go until the end of the word end then turn around and check if the last 3 characters are 175. That seems intuitive to me.

Is it necessary to use regex?
content ='12345 67890 123175 9876'
for item in content.split(' '):
    if not item.endswith('175'):
        print(item)

Output
12345
67890
9876


A good candidate for a list comprehension : [i for i in content.split() if not i.endswith('175')]

An other alternative would be numeric validation:
Take the number modulo 1_000 and verify if this equals 175:
def numeric_validation(s:list)->list:
    """use modulo to verify numbers last digits"""
    return [v for v in s.split() if not int(v)%1_000==175]


Functionally correct if all tokens are string representations of integers. However, very slow

@SIGHUP based on your answers benchmarking its in the same ballpark with func1,4

It's much slower than func4() on my platform
